Manipulating the $3x \text{ mod } 1$ map for a discrete 1d system
I am working through a text ("Chaos", by Alligood et at.) and an early Exercise (T1.12) asks to prove a property of the tripling map $$ 3x \text{ mod } 1$$ and I am getting really hung up on the algebraic manipulations that I think are required. I have very little experience with this function.
The Problem

Consider the $3x \text{ mod } 1$ map of the unit interval $\left[0,1\right]$. Define the distance between a pair of points $x,y$ to be either $\left|x-y\right|$ or $1 - \left|x-y\right|$, whichever is smaller. (a) Show that the distance between any pair of points that lie within 1/6 of one another is tripled by the map.

My Attempt
I start by defining $$ f\left(x\right) := 3x \text{ mod } 1, \; x\in\left[0,1\right] $$ and
$$ d\left(x,y\right) := \min \left\{ \left|x-y\right|, 1 - \left|x-y\right| \right\} \in \left[0, 1/2\right]. $$
The text hints that this distance, $d$, is a "circle metric," since the map $f$ can be interpreted as wrapping the unit interval three times around a circle, and $d$ clearly finds the minimum distance on that circle (in a sense).
Next I assume I have points $x,y \in \left[0,1\right]$ with $$ d\left(x,y\right) < 1/6,$$ so I have either of the cases $$\left|x-y\right| < 1/6$$ or $$1- \left|x-y\right| < 1/6 \iff 5/6 < \left|x-y\right| < 1. $$ From the definition, the distance between the image points is $$ d\left(f\left(x\right), f\left(y\right)\right) = \min \left\{ \left| f\left(x\right) - f\left(y\right) \right|, 1 - \left| f\left(x\right) - f\left(y\right) \right| \right\}. $$
I am trying to rewrite the $\left|f\left(x\right) - f\left(y\right)\right|$ in terms of $d\left(x,y\right)$, and I'm stuck. Both operands involve the absolute value quantity, which is $$ \left|f\left(x\right) - f\left(y\right) \right| = \left| 3x \text{ mod } 1 - 3y \text{ mod } 1 \right|. $$
I want to simplify this. Evidently we have $$ 3x \text{ mod } 1 - 3y \text{ mod } 1 \neq 3\left(x-y\right) \text{ mod } 1 ,$$ since, for example, $$ 1.2 \text{ mod } 1 - 1.9 \text{ mod } 1 = 0.2 - 0.9 = -0.7 $$ but $$ \left(1.2 - 1.9\right) \text{ mod } 1 = \left(-0.7\right) \text{ mod } 1 = 0.3.$$ I found this website where the author claims to solve this problem by performing exactly this algebraic manipulation, which I don't trust.
Even if this identity were true, I'd still be stuck with the mod in my formula, so I'm suspecting there's a more clever way to solve this problem. I'd appreciate any ideas!

The best is really to take the advice that you mention about the circle.
This means the following.
Considering the function $h\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb C$ given by $g(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$, the map $f(x)=3x\bmod1$ on $[0,1]$ becomes the map $F(z)=z^3$ on the circle $C=h([0,1])$. More precisely,
$$
F\circ g=g\circ f.
$$
Moreover, the distance $d$ between two points in $C$ becomes the minimal angle between them.
Note that if the distance between two points $z,w\in C$ is $d(z,w)\le\frac16$, we have $$d(z^3,w^3)=3d(z,w)$$ since $d(z^3,w^3)\le\frac12$. This property fails in general when $d(z,w)>\frac16$ (just make a drawing).
Translating all this to the interval gives you the desired property.

Consider building up some lemmas to make life easier.

Prove that $d$ is translation invariant.
Prove that $f$ turns translations into translations.
Argue that without loss of generality, it suffices to consider $x=0$ and $y\in[0,\frac16]$. If necessary, make this argument formal by applying the right transformation to an arbitrary $x,y$ pair, using the previous lemmas.
Prove the desired inequality in this special case, and you're done!

